# pseudo Streaming dll failed to load in iis 7.0

Tags: iis-7, flowplayer, pseudo-streaming

I am getting this error when I add the handlers for implementing pseudo Streaming video mentioned in below url

```
http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Internet-Information-Services-IIS7-Version2
```

When I run the website from the IIS 7 web server the application pool gets stopped due to this error.
I am using asp.net 4.0, Windows OS 7 home premium. IIS 7 with all the features installed provided by IIS 7 on windows

The screen shot are attached below

```
Error 1 on IIS 7
```

[image: Error 1 on IIS 7]

```
Error 2 on IIS 7
```

[image: Error 2 on IIS 7]

and when I browse the application through iis i get this on my browser

```
Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

When I remove pseudo Streaming video handler mapping from my IIS every thing works fine I have no problem open my website through IIS . but I need to implement pseudo Streaming video in my website

Comment: Properbly the input video was corrupt.

Comment: the video format is .MP4 and it plays fine when i use visual studio 2012 local IIS to debug my application . It only crashes when i use the IIS 7.0 to run my application i.e after adding all the mod_h264_streaming.dll refrences in the IIS 7.0 handler. how check that is due to the .MP4 issue. i will give it a new .MP4 file and get back to you.

Comment: I know a strange bug where windows is not able to show jpg images. Which windows version are on the server and your local computer?

Comment: i currently working on my local machine not a deployment yet. i have window 7 as my OS

Comment: i have changed the input video same issue

Comment: strange no idea sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue kindly check the below links. i just re-did everything from the start

http://flowplayer.org/forum/#!/moot/11467